# Run-time error '1004' : Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed. How to access named range stored in variable?

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am trying to assign a named range to a variable, and then reference it.

The named range is scoped to the entire workbook, so I shouldn't have to reference the sheet.

```vb
Sub my_function()
    
    Sheets("TEST").Select
    numRange = Range("num")

    Range(numRange).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert shift:=xlToRight
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your plan with this? You have no defined variable types. Do you assing values to `numRange` or do you want to assign a range object? The problem right now is that you have not set `numrange` as a range but you try to use it as such. My guess is that there is a value in `num` that would act as an indirect range value?

Comment: it was just a simple code to select a named range in a spreadsheet. So yes i think i need to set is as a range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without dimming your variables, VBA will try to assign their own. Depending on what your named range `Num` entitles (single cell or (discontinues) range) the behaviour will differ.

My guess is that you are trying to use an indirect cell reference that sits in `num` being a single cell. In that case the basic VBA for that would look like:

```
Dim numRange As Range
With Sheets("TEST")
    Set numRange = .Range(.Range("num"))
End With
```

So let's say, if `num` refers to `B1`, and the value in `B1` is a written reference to `A1:A5` then `numRange` will now hold the range object with address: `$A$1:$A$5`

if my guess is wrong and you just want to have the named range as an range object then there is no need to `Set` it again, it is allready a range object. Simply refer to it as (for example):

```
With Sheets("TEST")
    .Range("num").Select
End With
```

However, you should really avoid the use of `.Select`

Answer (score 2):

You should [Avoid Using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in general. Try this code instead:

```
Dim numRange As Range
Set numRange = Sheets("TEST").Range("num")

numRange.Copy
numRange.Offset(, numRange.Columns.Count).Insert xlShiftToRight
```

You could of course also skip assigning it to a separate range object and use it inside a `With` block like this:

```
With Sheets("TEST").Range("num")
    .Copy
    .Offset(, .Columns.Count).Insert xlShiftToRight
End With
```

Comment: You could of course access it directly, I added that to my answer. I would probably still prefer to assign it to a range object, since I feel it makes it easier to handle. This is debatable of course, and I agree that this use case is simple enough to do it this way.

Comment: Looks much cleaner ;)